# magento payment method

Tags: magento, payment-gateway

I have created magento payment method, but after creating order with this method in admin area block **Payment Information** shows only **Order was placed using USD**

Other payment methods automatically attache title here (like standart saved cc / check money order / etc.)

Can anyone tell what I must to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

By default payment information is displayed in the adminhtml order view using the template app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/payment/info/default.phtml (sometimes payment info blocks set a different one).
In that template the payment method title is output using

```
<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getMethod()->getTitle()) ?>
```

The method `Mage_Payment_Block_Info::getMethod()` simply returns an instance of the payment method.

The method `getTitle()` already is implemented in `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract`.

```
public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->getConfigData('title');
}
```

This means you only need to set the title in the configuration of your payment method at `payment/$methodCode/title` and you are set.

Comment: Thanx for comment. Yes - I know that and exactly so I done. In config I have `payment/lacpaycs/title` and in my payment method model I have `$_code='lacpaycs'` (code to add totals works with this well), but in admin area I have no method displayed. And I don't use any adminhtml so I can't rewrite that. Will try to find some typo may be (((

Comment: Also this title shone well on payment methods tab, where magento get it from same `payment/lacpaycs/title` - so with title all OK but in some reason it not appears in admin area

Comment: What template is being used? Also, is the correct payment info block set?

Comment: template base/default, used layout.xml, but in layout only loading 1 js in head section. Info block appearing well if we talking about frontend. In info block title getting by `$this->getMethod()->getTitle()`

Comment: base/default in the adminhtml area? Did you add the `app/design/adminhtml/base/default` fallback directories? We are talking about the admin area, right?

Comment: nope - I don't use any adminhtml in this extention at all. I have no need with that. In admin area I only use configuration which automatically added by system.xml

Comment: I didn't know that I must create my own info block in adminhtml if I use infoblock in frontend. I created one ane putting information I need to it - so thanx for help